# Entity Framework and deep sync

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, synchronization

I need to get update local DB to have actual data from external resource.
Model has the following structure:

```
public class Invoice
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime InvoiceDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedTime { get; set; }

    public string CustomerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }

    private ICollection<InvoiceLineItem> _invoiceLineItems;
    public virtual ICollection<InvoiceLineItem> InvoiceLineItems { get => _invoiceLineItems ??= new List<InvoiceLineItem>(); protected set => _invoiceLineItems = value; }

}
```

and related entity:

```
public class InvoiceLineItem 
{
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal? Amount { get; set; }
    public decimal? Price { get; set; }
    public string TaxCode { get; set; }

    public string InvoiceId { get; set; }
    public virtual Invoice Invoice { get; set; }
}
```

so, as we can see, one invoice can have zero, one or many items inside

First time I get from external resource invoice with its items. It's easy:

```
var newRecurringInvoice = _mapper.Map<Invoice>(recurringInvoiceRemote);
_dataContext.RecurringInvoices.Add(newRecurringInvoice);
```

But when record with such Id already exists, it's a little complex.
Possible situations:

- new item is added to remote source and we need to add its locally
- item is deleted from remote source and we need to remove its locally
- item without changes (identically on both resources)
- item with the same Id is changed (one or several fields) and we need to update locally

How to do it? Is it enough for do it only

```
localRecurringInvoice = _mapper.Map<InvoiceDto, Invoice>(recurringInvoiceRemote, localRecurringInvoice);
_dataContext.RecurringInvoices.Update(localRecurringInvoice);
```

or need to do carefully for every case? How to do it better? As I understand, it's standard common situation

**ADDED #1**

full code is in loop, looks like:

```
        foreach (var recurringInvoiceRemote in remoteRecurringInvoices)
        {
            var localRecurringInvoice = localExistingRecurringInvoices.Where(a => a.Id == recurringInvoiceRemote.Id).FirstOrDefault();
            if (localRecurringInvoice != null)
            {
                // update existing
                localRecurringInvoice = _mapper.Map<RecurringInvoiceDto, RecurringInvoice>(recurringInvoiceRemote, localRecurringInvoice);
                _dataContext.RecurringInvoices.Update(localRecurringInvoice);
            }
            else
            {
                // add new
                var newRecurringInvoice = _mapper.Map<RecurringInvoice>(recurringInvoiceRemote);
                _dataContext.RecurringInvoices.Add(newRecurringInvoice);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Before updating, get current record from database and then map DTO to this record and do NOT call `Update`, EF Core will detect changes automatically and even will not send update statement if entity is not changed.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I do it in loop and `localRecurringInvoice` is rewritten in every cycle (I will update main post soon). Without calling `Update` entity will be updated (if necessary) in any way? Thank you!